# Filtering queryset by next 30 days and date passed

Tags: python, django, datetime

I'm not sure if It's due to lack of sleep, but I cannot for the life of me figure out what's causing this issue.

```
AttributeError: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'utcoffset'
```

I'm trying to filter a queryset based on two conditions.

1. If the date has already passed.
2. If the date is within the next 30 days.

Model

```
class Member(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    ...
    membership_expiry = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    club_membership_expiry = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    medical_expiry = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

View get_context_data override

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MembershipReport, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        members = Member.objects.all()
        now = date.today()
        thirty_days = now + timedelta(days=30)
        context['membership_overdue'] = members.filter(Q(membership_expiry__lte=now) | Q(membership_expiry__gte=now, membership_expiry__lte=thirty_days))
        return context
```

I've tried using `date.today()` `datetime.now()` and django's `timezone.now()` all three throw the same error.

Comment: Did you try looking through te documentation to see which datetime object does have a `utcoffset` attribute? then try to use that one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was lack of sleep. Posting this here because of the other answers gave me some clarity and helped fix the naive problem. However the error was actually because I was calling `naturaltime` on a date object instead of `naturalday` from the `humanize` lib.

Answer (score 3):

try this,

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now(tz=pytz.UTC)
```